# How to access ui-grid cell form instance from the Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-grid

I know that there already exists some posts with this question, but my context is different.

I have a grid with this available columns:

```
controller.availableColumns = [
    {field: 'dpmId', displayName: 'dpm id', width: '100', enableCellEdit: false},
    {field: 'value', displayName: 'value', width: '100', editableCellTemplate: editableCellTemplate}
]
```

and the template is:

```
var editableCellTemplate = '<div>' +
    '<div ng-form name="conceptsCellEditorForm">' +
    '<input name="conceptsCellEditor" class="form-control" ui-grid-editor ng-model="row.entity[col.field]" ' +
       'ng-pattern="grid.appScope.conceptsController.myRegex" style="padding-right:20px; float:left" />' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';
```

so how can I access the form instance from the Angular controller

```
$scope['conceptsCellEditorForm'].$valid
```

but the form is undefined so I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined
```

I have added a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uKxWyg4HrBbkq5YcyMLZ?p=preview) to describe my exact issue (line 66).

Comment: The problem is that the form from the custom cell template is available only to the controller from the specific directive that is rendering it, so unfortunately it is not available to the controller containing the whole grid.

Comment: so there is no way to access the form within the grid?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this component, but I guess it is not possible unless it exports validation status through its API. I've glanced over the documentation but was unable to find such API. You may be able to add this feature without much effort.

Comment: The `scope` is at the controller level, but you are creating a template for each individual cell. Each of those cells have their own `scope`. Either put the form at the controller level (can't be used as a cell template) which would expose it on `$scope` or have the cell evaluate it's own `scope` by using `$scope.gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit`.